# UISearchBar and two UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I hope everybody is fine. I'm new to iOS programming and I have a question. In my app I have an UISearchBar and two UITableView. The first UItableView is the one the have the list of items and I want to use the second one to display the result that I get from the UISearch. My question is if there is a way that I can connect the second UITable to display the result? I think using control and dragging it but it didnt work. Please is anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need 2 tables. IOS has UISearchDisplayController component which already has 2 tables, one for showing data and one for search results.
I suggest you to read this article http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-create-a-searchable-uitableview/ 
and to download project from it https://github.com/versluis/Table-Seach-2013